# Deploying a plugin for MS Dynamics CRM - missing assembly

Tags: plugins, assemblies, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have followed the steps from this link, and created a plugin:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb955365.aspx

I have registered it on a Retrieve message for one of my entities, but when it triggers  I get this error:

> Web Service Plug-in failed in
> OrganizationId:
> a2dcffbc-e056-4971-adfb-662979139800;
> SdkMessageProcessingStepId:
> 5b6921b8-192e-e011-846c-001d0928c4ac;
> EntityName: new_csvproiect; Stage: 50;
> MessageName: Retrieve; AssemblyName:
> MSDynCRMPlugin.Plugin, MSDynCRMPlugin,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=a6a43dc7a3dcc61d;
> ClassName: MSDynCRMPlugin.Plugin;
>
> Exception: Unhandled Exception:
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could
> not load file or assembly
> 'System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
> one of its dependencies. The system
> cannot find the file specified.    at
> MSDynCRMPlugin.Plugin.Execute(IPluginExecutionContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.PluginStep.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext
> context)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your plugin project is set to target the .NET 4 framework, NOT The .NET 4 Client Profile framework. With Visual Studio 2010, the default for new projects appears to be .NET 4 Client Profile.

I think that references to System.Web.Services will compile under .NET 4 Client Profile, but will actually fail to execute when you run them.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to merge outside assemblies into your plugin dll. Here are the instructions you should follow: [Using ILMerge with CRM Plugin Assemblies](http://www.2wconsulting.com/2010/11/using-ilmerge-with-crm-plugin-assemblies/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
        {
            String resourceName = "AssemblyLoadingAndReflection." + new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";

            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];

                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);

                return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }
        };
```

Comment: This answer is not useful, because it does not explain why this code would help solve the issue.